Is the death penalty for sins of lust a proportionate punishment?
In the New Law, is the death penalty for sodomy (or other sins of lust, like fornication or adultery) a proportionate punishment? In other words, do Catholic theologians say legislators are morally permitted to write a law requiring the death penalty for homosexual or other acts of lust?
Under the Old Law, Lev 20:13 did proscribe sodomy with capital punishment.
cf. this post to the CathInfo thread "What Trump policies show he is pro-abortion or pro-sodomy?"

Capital punishment in the O.T. is symbolic of final judgement in the N.T.. All forms of sexual immorality will receive final judgement at the 2nd resurrection which is called the 2nd death. It doesn't matter what the sexual sin is. So the question of proportion is really a question of God's righteousness and authority. Is that something you really want to bring into question?

@Biff I'm asking about human law.

You specified the 'New Law' in your question. Romans 8 makes a distinction between the old law and the new law. There is nothing in your question about a law given by humans as opposed to from God.

I f the nation state of Israel in the OT was the equivalent of The Church in the NT, then the NT equivalent of the death penalty for all unrepented sexual sins would be excommunication from the Church not death. Repentance would be needed before reinstatement.

Homosexuality is a different kind of sin from heterosexual fornication and adultery, the act in and of itself is contrary to nature, whereas these heterosexual sins are only sinful because there is something accidentally lacking in the participants - namely, they are not married to one another. That's going to factor into the answer, as a crime against nature will necessarily have a graver penalty than crimes which are grave, but not against nature as such.
